# writing a polyalphabetic transposition cipher in java

Tags: java, encryption

This is what I have currently. It's supposed to find the letter entered in plaintext, match it (case sensitive) to the letter in the alphabet then shift over depending on the number entered oddkey or evenkey which i'll implement later. But currently, this is the output I get.

```
what would you like to encrypt?
abcdefg
enter oddkey
1
Now enter the evenkey
1
B
BB
BBB
BBBB
BBBBB
BBBBBB
BBBBBBB
```

And this is the beginning of the code

```
String PlainText = "", cipherText = "";  
String alpha = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz- ";  
System.out.println("what would you like to encrypt?");  
PlainText = input.nextLine();  
System.out.println("enter oddkey");  
oddkey = input.nextInt();  
System.out.println("Now enter the evenkey");  
evenkey = input.nextInt();  

for ( int i = 0; i < PlainText.length(); i ++)  
       {for (int m = 1; m < alpha.length(); m ++ )  
            {if (alpha.charAt(m-1) == PlainText.charAt(i));  
                  cipherText = cipherText + alpha.charAt(m - 1 + evenkey);  
                  System.out.println(cipherText);   
}}
```

So what am I doing wrong that it is just repeating BBBBBBB instead of shifting the letters properly? Any advice?

Comment: And your question is???

Comment: sorry, added it to the end.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is two-fold.

1) You need to take a moment to properly indent your code so it is easily readable.

2) Your if condition is invalid (won't even compile). You need an opening curly brace `{` after the if preferably, but definitely not a semicolon.

I think if you change the if block to this it will get you past your issue:

```
for ( int i = 0; i < PlainText.length(); i ++) {
        for (int m = 1; m < alpha.length(); m ++ ) {
                if (alpha.charAt(m-1) == PlainText.charAt(i)){
                    cipherText = cipherText + alpha.charAt(m - 1 + evenkey);  
                    System.out.println(cipherText);   
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. And sorry for the formatting, was my first post so i'll definitely keep that in mind. What you did was exactly what I needed :D